# Is it possible to stop ViewModel Decimal properties forcing "required" validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a viewmodel with a property defined like so:

```
public decimal decProperty { get; set; }
```

I have found this enforced "required" validation when I would like to allow nulls. To me specifying 0.00 is explicitly different to null ie the user is stating that the value is 0.00 while the latter means that the value is n/a.

The only way around this that I have found is to redefine the property as a string with regex validation:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d+(\.\d{1,2})?", ErrorMessage = "Invalid decimal")]
public string strProperty { get; set; }
```

I am correct in my thinking and solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `decimal` property cannot ever be `null` though, try `decimal?` instead:

```
public decimal? decProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a nullable decimal:

```
public decimal? decProperty { get; set; }
```

Doing so, if the user doesn't provide any value for the `decProperty`, it's value would be `null`. Otherwise, it would contain the value that the user provided.

This cannot be done with `decimal`, because null is not a valid decimal value. On the other hand a nullable decimal can has a a value the `null` or any valid decimal value.

If you want to read more about nullable types, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).